# Find & Replace: disable dialog box asking to check rest of document

Tags: replace, ms-word, office365, ms-office

I often want to select a section of text and make replacements just within the selection. After finishing the replacements, a dialog box appears: "We made X replacements in your selection. Do you want to search the rest of the document? [Yes][No]"

I'd like to disable that dialog box. Any thoughts on how to do it?